# Draw angle arc inside the shape[steep angle]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i have a four points. its draggable. at any point i click 'draw' button i want to show the angles. i tried but it will draw arc outside for steep angle. but i want to draw the arc inside the shape at any point.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var a1 = parseInt($("#p1").css("left")) - 5;
var a2 = parseInt($("#p1").css("top")) - 5;
var b1 = parseInt($("#p2").css("left")) - 5;
var b2 = parseInt($("#p2").css("top")) - 5;
var c1 = parseInt($("#p3").css("left")) - 5;
var c2 = parseInt($("#p3").css("top")) - 5;
var d1 = parseInt($("#p4").css("left")) - 5;
var d2 = parseInt($("#p4").css("top")) - 5;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(a1, a2)
ctx.lineTo(b1, b2)
ctx.lineTo(c1, c2)
ctx.lineTo(d1, d2)
ctx.lineTo(a1, a2)
ctx.fillStyle = '#E6E0EC';
ctx.fill();
ctx.strokeStyle = "#604A7B";
ctx.lineWidth = "3"
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
$("#p1,#p2,#p3,#p4").draggable({
    drag: function () {

        a1 = parseInt($("#p1").css("left")) - 5;
        a2 = parseInt($("#p1").css("top")) - 5;
        b1 = parseInt($("#p2").css("left")) - 5;
        b2 = parseInt($("#p2").css("top")) - 5;
        c1 = parseInt($("#p3").css("left")) - 5;
        c2 = parseInt($("#p3").css("top")) - 5;
        d1 = parseInt($("#p4").css("left")) - 5;
        d2 = parseInt($("#p4").css("top")) - 5;

        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(a1, a2)
        ctx.lineTo(b1, b2)
        ctx.lineTo(c1, c2)
        ctx.lineTo(d1, d2)
        ctx.lineTo(a1, a2)
        ctx.fillStyle = '#E6E0EC';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#604A7B";
        ctx.lineWidth = "3"
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

});

$("#draw").click(function () {

    var dx1 = a1 - b1;
    var dy1 = a2 - b2;
    var dx2 = c1 - b1;
    var dy2 = c2 - b2;
    var ax1 = Math.atan2(dy1, dx1);
    var ax2 = Math.atan2(dy2, dx2);
    var a = parseInt((ax2 - ax1) * 180 / Math.PI + 360) % 360;

    /// detect if arc is inside or outside polygon:
    var aa = ax1 + 0.25;
    var x = b1 + 20 * Math.cos(aa);
    var y = b2 + 20 * Math.sin(aa);
    var isInside = ctx.isPointInPath(x, y);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(b1, b2);        
    ctx.arc(b1, b2, 20, ax1, ax2, !isInside);

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.25;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText((isInside ? a : 360-a) + '°', b1 + 15, b2);

});
});
```

please lookout the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/BKK5z/6/

Thank in advance.

**in chrome i get result like this**

[image]

**in firefox i get result like this**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, turns out the problem is not so much related to the point-in-path but rather with path itself.

### The problem

When there where only a single arc drawn the previous path was used to detect if the point was inside the polygon or not.

When the other three arcs are added the previous path now becomes the last drawn arc instead. This way the inside polygon detection will not be able to return the proper state as it will test with the arc instead.

### Solution

**[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/BKK5z/9/)**

Re-factor the code so that the original path of the polygon can be recreated before each check. This is a relative fast process as we don't have to draw anything to canvas to get a valid path (the costly part is the drawing itself).

**Do the following to fix -**

First create a generic function to create the path. This method can be used for rendering as well as checking path only:

```
function createPath(a1,a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(a1, a2);
    ctx.lineTo(b1, b2);
    ctx.lineTo(c1, c2);
    ctx.lineTo(d1, d2);
    //ctx.lineTo(a1, a2); /// not needed
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Now modify the draw method:

```
drag: function () {

    a1 = parseInt($("#p1").css("left")) - 5;
    ... snipped ...

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    createPath(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2);  /// use here
    
    ctx.fillStyle = '#E6E0EC';
    ctx.fill();
    ... snipped ...
}
```

This will render the polygon as before.

Now the key thing, recreate the path for each arc that is drawn but without rendering it:

```
$("#draw").click(function () {
    createPath(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2);
    draw(a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2);
    
    createPath(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2);
    draw(b1,c1,d1,b2,c2,d2);
    
    createPath(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2);
    draw(c1,d1,a1,c2,d2,a2);
    
    createPath(a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2);
    draw(d1, a1, b1, d2, a2, b2);

});
```

A second minor issue is the "sensitivity" of that infamous delta value. Up-adjust it a bit again to ~0.20-ish and you should be good to go.

As I mentioned in the previous answer, the ideal solution for this value is to calculate an "average" between the two angles so the angle is in the middle of the arc.

Comment: @v.ArunKumar no problem, there is still this issue with very narrow angle. I cannot get my head to wrap around the math needed to calc the mid point of the arc (its 4am which is probably why). :) In any case see if that works for now.

Comment: @Ken I'm feeling frustrated because I don't understand what the OP wanted.  It's cool you got it worked out for him.  Could you also ease my frustration by explaining what he wanted to do?

Comment: Hey @markE, sure I can try - I eventually understood it this way; that OP wanted to always draw the arc on the inside of the polygon. If the polygon was dragged into some "distorted" position some angles would "wrap" around and end up on the outside of the corner(s) and some on the inside (polygon face). He wanted all arcs on the inside no matter the polygon shape. Hope that eased the frustration a bit (yeah.. I know that feeling sometimes too).

Comment: @Ken Ahhhh...so if the polygon lines cross the angle indicators should always be "inside".  Thanks for restoring my sanity :)

Comment: @markE no problem! I usually have the opposite effect (says my wife) :)

Comment: @ken this file works well in chrome but not in firefox. please refer above images.

Comment: @v.ArunKumar I have really no more to offer on this. I already recommended you to use another method to calculate the mid-point angle. I showed you the *principle* in my answer (to detect point inside the polygon) and I haven't shown the exact formula as that would require a bit work. You should do some effort on your part as SO is not meant to be a place to get free key-ready code to go. I realize I have perhaps been to generous (?) in the past (I consider changing that in general). If you feel the answer is wrong you can always unaccept it (though I think I covered what you need to do).

Comment: @ken Really sorry to trouble you. i understand. thanks for your help. Have a great day:-)

Comment: @ken answer pls:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698447/degree-text-needs-to-be-aligned-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you so much Ken! Works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

**[ Updated answer with demo that allows draggable corner points ]**

Here is a demo showing **inside angles** where you can drag the corner points:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6ujbL/

Here is a demo showing **outside angles** where you can drag the corner points:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9kGmw/

If you want to draw an angle-symbol on an inside angle you can call this function by supplying corner (vertex) points in counter-clockwise order: point3, point2, point1:

```
function drawAngleSymbol(pt3,pt2,pt1){ ... }
```

If you want to draw an angle-symbol on an outside angle you can call this same function and supplying corner points in clockwise order: point1, point2, point3:

```
function drawAngleSymbol(pt1,pt2,pt3){ ... }
```

Comment: See the fiddles added to my answer for both outside angles (large sweeping) and inside angles (small sweeping)

Comment: Yes, just provide any 3 consecutive corner points on your polygon and these functions will illustrate your angles.  See the fiddles. :)

Comment: I updated my fiddles to let you drag the anchor points.  There is one fiddle for the inside angles and another for the outside angles.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: I really don't know what more to offer!   I gave you a rectangle with draggable corners and examples for showing inner angles and then showing outer angles. My answer matches your desired illustrations.  I'm feeling frustrated by my inability to understand what you want.   :-x