# Degree text needs to be aligned in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

In this fiddle the four pink dots movable[its draggable]. it forms any polygon shape. while clicking the draw button it draw each corner angle. this will be fine. but i need a degree text infront of the arc.

Existing one:

[image]

I need like this:

[image]

```
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(b1, b2);

    ctx.arc(b1, b2, 20, ax1, ax2, !isInside);
    console.log(ax1, ax2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.25;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText((isInside ? a : 360 - a) + '°', b1 + 15, b2);
```

Its possible. thanks in advance.

see This fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/yn4yg/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/natalieperna/6F3p7/1/

1. Find the bisection of `ax1` and `ax2`
2. Check if it's pointing inside the polygon (different than the existing `isInside` var), and if not add PI
3. Set text location 30 down bisection angle
4. Shift text location 5 to the left to account for length of the label

Answer (score 3):

**Your code contains the same math necessary to answer your question ???!**

```
ctx.arc(b1, b2, 20, ax1, ax2, !isInside);
```

- Bisect the angle ax2,ax1.
- If the sweep is counterclockwise then add PI (normalize within 2*PI if necessary).
- Optionally subtract a bit from the bisected angle to account for the small text length.
- Calculate the point from b1/b2 extending at least 20 pixels at the bisected angle.

Comment: please provide fiddle for this.

Comment: The required math is explained in my answer.

Comment: I tried it doesn't work for me. pls refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yn4yg/5/

Comment: You need to also do the last part.  Use the same trigonometry you used previously.  Calculate the texts X/Y by extending from the centerpoint at the bisected angle. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This should get you close to what you want:

```
// Get the starting and ending points of the arc
var angle = (isInside ? a : 360 - a);
var s_x = b1+20*Math.cos(ax1);
var s_y = b2+20*Math.sin(ax1);
var e_x = b1+20*Math.cos(ax2);
var e_y = b2+20*Math.sin(ax2);

ctx.fillText(angle + '°', ((s_x+e_x)/2), ((s_y+e_y)/2));
```

Here's the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/WYLKN/).